# Angular ui-bootstrap progressbar with angular-timer not showing value

Tags: javascript, angularjs, timer, progress-bar, angular-ui-bootstrap

Please help. I am fresh out of sanity.

See [codepen here for an example](http://codepen.io/cakesmith/pen/mEBKl).

I have a `<timer>` from [angular-timer](http://siddii.github.io/angular-timer/) that exposes `seconds` on to the local scope and updates it every second, which is pretty nice. Something like this:

```
<timer> {{seconds}} </timer>
```

So, I thought it would also be pretty nice to then use a `<progressbar>` from angular-ui-bootstrap and have it update the `value` on each tick. So, I've gone and done something like this:

```
<timer>
  <progressbar value="seconds"></progressbar>
</timer>
```

This, much to my amazement, does not work.

So, I went ahead and thought about it for what seems like two full days. That's probably because it's been two days of banging away at this and I still have no idea what in the world is going on. Anyway, I thought "hey, maybe somehow `seconds` isn't *reeeeeally* exposed on the scope, so let's find out if it is, OK? OK." (maybe talking to myself isn't helping.)

So, I proceeded to type these things:

```
<timer>
  {{seconds}}
  <progressbar value="seconds"></progressbar>
</timer>
```

and there they are, in all their glory, the seconds. On my page. Just not in my progressbar. Where I want them. Of course.

So, `seconds` is definitely exposed on the scope.

Then, I thought "okay. Seconds is on the scope. Maybe progressbar has an isolated scope that isn't inheriting `seconds` or something. Maybe. But no. I do not believe this is the case. That would make too much sense.

*Any* help would be like an oasis in a vast desert of frustration.

Comment: I suspect the progress bar has an isolated scope and you are running into the prototypal inheritance gotcha described [here](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes)

Comment: I thought that too, however wouldn't that mean that `$parent.seconds` would work? Because that doesn't work either. I tried adding a `$watch` on `seconds` in a new controller, updating a property and then using that, but that doesn't work either. I've updated the [pen](http://codepen.io/cakesmith/pen/mEBKl) to reflect these scenarios.

Comment: Also, that would mean that setting $scope.value with $interval wouldn't work either. But it does.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It doesn't work because <timer/> is not isolating the seconds object and therefore not exposing it to outside of its scope, while <progressbar/> isolates the value object. 
To make it work with a common scope you can use the timer-tick event that is fired according to the interval that is defined on the by the timer - and register to this event later
[Updated codepan](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KmEuL)

```
<div ng-controller="customCtrl">
  <timer interval="1000">
    {{seconds}}
    <progressbar value="timerSeconds"></progressbar>
  </timer>
</div>

app.controller('customCtrl', function($scope) {
 $scope.$on('timer-tick',function(e, val) {
   $scope.timerSeconds = (Math.floor(val.millis / 1000));
 }); 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to use progressbar directive in this case, as there is no javascript in the bootstrap implementation :

```
<timer start-time='start' end-time='end'">
   <div class="progress">
      <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width:{{ 100 - (100 * millis/(endTime - startTime)) | number:0}}%;">
      </div>
   </div>
 </timer>
```

Note : the example given in the angular-timer docmentation does not work if you use bootstrap 2. For bootstrap 3, you should use code above